# PHP/Laravel - Updating SQL integer column in row adds 1 to the value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this weird problem, where I'm trying to update an entry into my SQL database and it keeps adding 1 when I increase the value of the column and save it.

For example, I `+= 1` to the existing value of an entry of 2, the result is 3, but when saved it is logged as 4 in the database...
The column structure is int(20) unsigned.

PHP:

```
$quantity = 1;
$item = \App\item::find($item_id);
$item->items_sold += $quantity;
$item->save();
```

if I `dd($item->items_sold)` the result is correct, and the value is changed by the specified amount. However when I check the database, the value is increased by the specified amount and then increased again by 1...

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thankyou :)

Comment: Do you perhaps run this snippet twice? Without seeing the context, or how you execute it, that question remains unanswered.

Comment: Its inside a controller that runs once, I have die and dump straight after the save, and also an extra exit() just to make sure :)

Comment: There's nothing at all here that indicates it should be incremented twice. So this is something we need more info on, and you need to debug it further. If you for example append the value before and after to an array, then fetch it again after the `save()` again, and then dump that array with the two values, and the new object (freshly from the DB), you'll see If it incremented once or twice. Also keep in mind that even if the controller executes it once, the controller may be called twice somehow.

Comment: My guess is that you somehow run the script twice when you think you're only running it once. Please add some logging near this piece of code and check if it really run once for your every +2 increment (e.g. Add a [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) call before the `$item->save` statement and re-run it. Then check the server log / php-fpm log for clue).

Answer (score 1):

> The query builder also provides convenient methods for incrementing or
>   decrementing the value of a given column [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#increment-and-decrement)

```
\App\item::find($item_id)->increment('items_sold',1);
```